# Store coordinate to real time Database in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, core-location

I am trying to save lat. and long. to database. But the database doesn't show anything and it didn't show any error in Swift. My code is shown below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() == true {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .restricted || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

    let userLatitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
    let userLongtitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
    let userTime = locationManager.location?.timestamp

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: "test@gmail.com",password: "xxxx", completion: {(User, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.displayMyalertMessage(userMessage: error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("Success")
        }
        guard let uid = User?.user.uid else {return}
        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL:"")
        let userReference = ref.child("Locations").child(uid)

        let values = ["Latitude": userLatitude as Any, "Longtitude": userLongtitude as Any, "Time": UserTime as Any] as [String : Any]
        userReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reference) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
                return
            }
        })   
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func initiateLocation(){

    locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 100
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true

        //checkForLocationServices()
        checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()
    guard let myLatitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude else{
        return
    }
    guard let myLongitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude else{
        return
    }

}


func checkLocationAuthorizationStatus() {
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined{
        print("NotDetermined")
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }else {
        print("Problem with authorization")
    }
}



// Handle incoming location events.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
    print("Location: \(location)")
    updateMyLocationToDataBase()
}


// Handle authorization for the location manager.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .restricted:
        print("Location access was restricted.")
    case .denied:
        print("User denied access to location.")
        // Display the map using the default location.
    case .notDetermined:
        print("Location status not determined.")
    case .authorizedAlways: fallthrough
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        print("Location status is OK.")            
    }
}

// Handle location manager errors.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    print("Error: \(error)")

    let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as! String

    let msg :String = "You have denied the app to access your location. Please enable the location services in your settings for the app to get the location";
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Allow \(appName) to access your location while you are using the app?", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SETTINGS", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
            return
        }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
            })
        }
    }


    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(settingsAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```